# Activiti Explorer - Request resource is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, explorer, activiti

I have big problem to run activiti-explorer when i try access: `http://localhost:8080/activiti-explorer/` tomcat shows me `HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available.` I'm really don't have any idea why that dosen't work. Can you help me?

This what have I done on my PC:

- I'm using `5.19.0` version of activiti-explorer
- `7.0.63` tomcat
- `JDK 1.8.0.77` (i think there is no point to downgrade java to previous versions (<=1.7) becouse my main application using this version)
- I'm sure I have correctly configured environment variables (`JAVA_HOME`,`JRE_HOME`,`PATH`,`CATALINA_HOME`)
- I configured data base connection (`db.properties`, `context.xml`) in `activiti-explorer.war` and i moved this file to `tomcat/webapps`
- I don't have any errors about activiti during tomcat start

Answer (score 1):

Check if activiti explorer is deployed to tomcat in manager.

```
http://{host}:{port}/manager/html
```

More info in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the catalina.out log. There will be something in there that leads you to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check Admin Console (cmd that runs behind) after hitting the link. most recent exception occurred will be displayed there.